# set header via perl function when invoked from sub_filter in nginx

Tags: perl, nginx

I would like to set header via perl or nginscript when invoked through sub_filter like below

```
perl_set $abc '
  sub {
        my $r = shift;
        my $v = 123; 
        $r->header_out("foo", $v);
        return $v;
    }
';

server {
   location  / {
         proxy_pass ...
         ....
         sub_filter  "XYZ"  $abc;
    }

}
```

I can see in response XYZ is getting replaced by 123, but header foo is not added.
I can't add that header directly in location directive as perl function getting called twice for example if I add header like below then I noticed perl function gets invoked during add_header and also during sub_filter

```
set $xyz $abc; 
add_header Foo $xyz;
sub_filter "XYZ"  $xyz;
```

Can anyone please help how to achieve this ?

Comment: Where does `$r` come from? Please show the full code you tried for the `perl_set` directive. Also, `$a` is a reserved variable used for `sort`. Don't use it for anything else.

Comment: From the examples in http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html it looks like `123` is not a good return value for that function.

Comment: $r comes like my $r = shift; as given in link which you posted, I am referring same link only.  Also just here I mentioned $a  actually its my $t = time();

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include that documentation link. Also inlcude that `$r = shift` part in your code.

Comment: Probably won't make a difference, but try setting the header to `"$t"` instead of `$t`.  (While Perl itself happily converts to strings where needed, other things integrated with Perl don't necessarily do it right.)

Comment: Also, do try with stripped down code that exactly matches what you are showing us.